# Azure AppService auto shutdown to save cost

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app service that I use from time to time (test env). How to configure it to auto-close when I do not use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Service always incurs cost so that is not possible. You can create it when you need it using some sort of automation (powershell\cli\arm templates\etc) and delete it after you dont need it.

another option - colocate it with some other App Service which you need all the time, so it will just use small fraction of that app resources (wont cost anything extra).

Comment: What do you exactly Jean by 'colocate'? To use another deployment slot?

Comment: no, just create another app service using the same app service plan

Comment: so within service plan I can create many serwices and the cost is the same as one service???

Comment: yes, app service plan is the same as a webfarm, basically. as long as there is enough resources for your app services to run on app service plan you are good

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use **[Dev/Test](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/dev-test/)** option if you are really worried about pricing.

> Dev/Test pricing applies only when you run the resources within an
>   Azure subscription that is based on one of the Dev/Test offer

Answer (score 2):

May be a delayed answer but I have found an elegant solution. There is a "Always ON" flag in the settings page that can be used for this purpose.

**Location**
AppService --> Configuration --> General Settings --> Platform Settings --> Always On.

**Usage**

> Always On: Keeps the app loaded even when there's no traffic. When Always On is not turned on (default), the app is unloaded after 20 minutes without any incoming requests. The unloaded app can cause high latency for new requests because of its warm-up time. When Always On is turned on, the front-end load balancer sends a GET request to the application root every five minutes. The continuous ping prevents the app from being unloaded.
> Always On is required for continuous WebJobs or for WebJobs that are triggered using a CRON expression.

Comment: Does this mean that when a user comes to the app to use it, say, the first user in the morning - that they have to wait whilst the app service starts - and get error messages in the mean time?  The restart time for a node or react Javascript app running on Azure (if restarted manually) is measured in minutes before it is fully available - which is totally unacceptable from a user perspective.

Answer (score 0):

For dev/test there is an app service plan that is free (it has the "Always On" setting turned off and disabled). Create a Free F1 app service plan and then assign your app service to use that plan.